# What happens if you induct your wife into the blades?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Will she stay with you in your house or stay at sky haven temple?

Answer (score 4):

You can talk to her and choose the option to choose the home you want her to live. If you choose one of your houses, she'll stay there, if you choose HER house, she has Sky Haven Temple set as her house, so she will stay there.